# Python: what type of object is here?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm struggling with the book LPTHW http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Here is the code:

```
def new(num_buckets=256):
    """Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap

def hash_key(aMap, key):
    """Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to
    an index for the aMap's buckets."""
    return hash(key) % len(aMap)

def get_bucket(aMap, key):
    """Given a key, find the bucket where it would go."""
    bucket_id = hash_key(aMap, key)
    return aMap[bucket_id]

def get_slot(aMap, key, default=None):
    bucket = get_bucket(aMap, key)
    for i, kv in enumerate(bucket):
        k, v = kv
        if key == k:
            return i, k, v
    return -1, key, default
```

What does `kv` means in `get_slot`? What type of object is this? Why the code below does not work? I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

```
for i, kv in enumerate([1,2,3,4,5]):
    k, v = kv
    print(kv)
```

Update:
It was a good idea to check one more time how `enumerate` works
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate . Thank everyone for the answers.

Comment: Do you understand what `enumerate` does? Do you understand why you have both `i` and `kv` in `for i, kv in ...`?

Comment: Try `for i, kv in enumerate([('foo', 1),  ('bar', 2), ('baz', 3)]):` instead..

Comment: kv stands for key, value pair, the constituent part of a dictionary (also called HashTable, map, associative array) in different languages. In your code on the bottom there is no such dictionary.

Comment: @VincentSavard, Honestly, I didn't. Somehow I missed the notion that kv should be iterable. I'll add a link for that function and add some code for get_bucket() to the post, to make more evident that  kv should be iterable for those ones who might have the same question the in future.

Comment: I'm glad you found both answers helpful! However, you can only mark one of them as accepted; pick the one that helped you most! Not marking either one accepted is a valid choice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) of tuples.  Each tuple is an index and a value.  For example, if you say `enumerate([2, 3, 4])`, you will get `(0, 2)`, `(1, 3)`, and `(2, 4)`.  Since you use `for i, kv in enumerate(...)`, the first iteration for example will have `i == 0` and `kv == 2`.  You then say `k, v = kv`, but `kv` is only one integer.  It is not a tuple or a list etc. so you can't split it into two variables.  If you were to say `enumerate([(2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7])` instead, you could do that because `i` would be `0` when `kv` is `(2, 3)`.  `kv` could be split into two variables so that `k` is `2` and `v` is `3`.

Comment: `enumerate()` returns an iterator, and yes that iterator generates tuples. It's misleading / confusing to say that "`enumerate()` returns a list of tuples".

Comment: @PM2Ring: Okay; I edited.  I hope he doesn't get confused by the unknown word `iterator`, though.

Comment: IT seems that the OP likes your answer. :) But feel free to explain what an iterator does, since that will make your answer more helpful for future readers. OTOH, Martijn kinda has that covered in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

`kv` is assigned one of the values in the sequence that `get_bucket(aMap, key)` produces; each iteration over `enumerate()` produces another one of those values (together with an integer counter, assigned to `i` in the example code). Apparently each one of those objects it *itself* an iterable with two elements.

Your attempt produced a list with just integers, which are not themselves iterable, which is why the `k, v = kv` assignment fails. Try this instead:

```
for i, kv in enumerate([('foo', 1), ('bar', 2), ('baz', 3)]):
    k, v = kv
```

This iterates over a sequence of `(str, int)` tuples, so the `k, v = kv` iterable unpacking works.

In general, all `enumerate()` does is add a sequence number; the default is to start at 0. So for each iteration in a `for` loop, `enumerate(something)` produces `(counter, value_from_something)`. That `value_from_something` is itself still just a Python object, which can support all sorts of operations.

You can see from the `new()` function in the same sample, that the code deals with a list of lists:

```
def new(num_buckets=256):
    """Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap
```

so `aMap` is a list containing other lists. The code refers to each of those lists as *buckets*. The `set()` function shows that those buckets contain *tuples* with two values, the key and the value:

```
else:
    # the key does not, append to create it
    bucket.append((key, value))
```

The `get_slot()` function handles one of those buckets, which contains 0 or more `(key, value)` pairs (and all the keys have hashed to the same bucket).